# Product of Array Except Self

Tags: python, c

I am doing exerices in the online judge website----leetcode.And in this problem, I can't find where is the problem.
In Python, even though the list is out of bounds, the oj shows accepted.
But in C, even though the array is not out of bounds, the oj shows runtime error.
Why?

Problem descripition:
Given an array of `n` integers where `n > 1`, nums, return an array output such that `output[i]` is equal to the product of all the elements of nums except `nums[i]`.

Solve it without division and in O(n).

For example, given `[1,2,3,4]`, return `[24,12,8,6]`.

Follow up:
Could you solve it with constant space complexity? (Note: The output array does not count as extra space for the purpose of space complexity analysis.)

Mycode:

Python:

```
class Solution(object):
def productExceptSelf(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    size = len(nums)
    output = [1] * size
    left = 1
    for x in range(size - 1):
        left *= nums[x]
        output[x + 1] *= left
    right = 1
    for x in range(size - 1, 0, -1):
        right *= nums[x]
        output[x - 1] *= right
    return output
```

C:

```
//Return an array of size *returnSize.
//Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
int *productExceptSelf(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
    int left = 1, right = 1;
    int i;    
    int resize[numsSize + 1];   
    for (i = 0 ; i < (numsSize + 1) ; i++)
        resize[i] = 1;        
    for (i = 0 ; i < numsSize ; i++)
        {
            left *= nums[i];
            resize[i + 1] *= left;
        }        
    for (i = numsSize ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            right *= nums[i];
            resize[i - 1] *= right;
        }
    returnSize = resize;
    return returnSize;
}
```

Comment: The comment says "The returned array must be malloced", but you didn`t do so. Also, do not return address of non-static local variable because the variable will vanish on exiting the function (block).

Comment: How do you use the C function? Do you use the variable you pass as `returnSize`, or the pointer returned by the function? Both will lead to *undefined behavior* but for different reasons.

Comment: You just tried to lie to the compiler because it was warning you about returning a local variable. Didn't you think of passing the allocated space through the `returnSize` pointer instead of allocating it locally in the function? Another thing would be `malloc()` but then you should be very careful with memory leaks. And as @JoachimPileborg points out, in the first case you didn't alter the passed pointer so you will try to read before write which is *Undefined Behavior*, In the second case you will read from deallocated memory, again *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate an array on the stack, and then return from the function.  That immediately deallocates all variable allocated on the stack for `productExceptSelf`, leaving the space free to be claimed by another function.  You don't copy the array when returning it, you're only return its address.  Usago of this address to try to access that array while it has been deallocated is what is causing the error.  As the comment suggests in your code, allocate the array with `malloc` and not by declaring it on the stack.  I.e do something like `int* someArray = malloc( n * sizeof(int));`

That being said, you have many issues with your management of pointers.  I'm not sure you understand very well how they work.  Your function is intended to return two values, the array of product itself and its final size.  Since `C` can directly return only one value, you actually return the array of type `int*` directly and you return the size of type `int` by writing that `int` at the address given by `resultSize`.  Namely you should do `*resultSize = myActualSize`.  For the array, you can do `return someArray`, that array *being allocated on the heap with `malloc`* as I said above.